# powershell networkinterface convert bytes to kilobytes

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to convert unit that bytes to kilobytes.

powershell command of bellow entered :

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface | 
select BytesReceivedPersec , BytesSentPersec , name | 
Where-Object {$_.name -cnotmatch "isatap"} | 
Where-Object {$_.name -cnotmatch "Teredo"} | 
Where-Object {$_.name -cnotmatch "로컬"} | 
% { '{0,10} {1,20} {2,20}' -f $_.BytesReceivedPersec, $_.BytesSentPersec , $_.name}
```

output :

```
627975  483072  Intel[R] 82575L Gigabit Network Connection
```

But output unit is Bytes
I want to convert unit that bytes to kilobytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `/1kb` to the `BytesReceived` expression and surround them with parentheses:

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface | 
select BytesReceivedPersec , BytesSentPersec , name | 
Where-Object {$_.name -cnotmatch "isatap|Teredo|로컬"} |
% { '{0,10} {1,20} {2,20}' -f ($_.BytesReceivedPersec /1kb), ($_.BytesSentPersec /1kb) , $_.name}
```

Also you can use `-cnotmatch {"isatap|Teredo|로컬"}` to short the code

Comment: WoW !! Thank you~~